# C++ Access violation exception when calling Matlab compiled function: null pointer mistake?

Tags: c++, matlab, access-violation, null-pointer

I've searched extensively but there seems not to be a satisfying answer to this question online. So I'm posting again this problem in case someone has found a solution.

I have written a C++ code that is supposed to call some Matlab code. I have compiled all my Matlab files using the following command:

```
mcc -N -W cpplib:libRTR2 -T link:lib RTR.m -v
```

I have included the header, DLL and LIB files created by above command in the 'Header Files'for my Visual Studio project. I have also includde mclmcrrt.lib, mclmcrrt.h and mclcppclass.h in the same.

Here is my C++ code:

```
#define BZZ_COMPILER 3
#include <stdint.h> 
#include "./hpp/BzzMath.hpp"
#include "libRTR2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "mclmcrrt.h"
#include "mclcppclass.h"

double RTRtest(BzzVector &x)
{

x(1);
mwArray out(1,1);
try {
    // create input
    double a[] = { x[1] };

    mwArray in1(1, 1, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);

    in1.SetData(a, 1);


    // call function

    RTR(1, out, in1);

    // show result
    std::cout << "objFun" << std::endl;
    std::cout << out << std::endl;

    double F[1];
    out.GetData(F, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i<1; i++) {
        std::cout << F[i] << " " << std::endl;
    }

}
catch (const mwException& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return -2;
}
catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "Unexpected error thrown" << std::endl;
    return -3;
}

// cleanup

return out;
}

int optim()
{
if (!mclInitializeApplication(NULL, 0))  {
    std::cerr << "could not initialize the application" << std::endl;
    mclGetLastErrorMessage();
    return -1;
}
if (!libRTR2Initialize()) {
    std::cerr << "Could not initialize the library" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

bzzFilePrint("BzzRobustMinimization.txt");
BzzVector Xmin(1, 2000.);
BzzVector Xmax(1, 5000.);
BzzVector X0(1, 2000.);
double F0 = RTRtest(X0);
BzzMinimizationRobust m(X0, F0, RTRtest, Xmin, Xmax);
m();
m.BzzPrint("Results");
libRTR2Terminate();
mclTerminateApplication();
}

int main()
{
mclmcrInitialize();
return mclRunMain((mclMainFcnType)optim, 0, NULL);

}
```

And when I try to debug it I obtain this error:

[Access Violation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZU4y.jpg)

I know it is related probably to trying to pass a null pointer to one of my functions, but being no expert in C++ I'm struggling to find where the error lies. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I've already tried to proceed step-by-step through my code _before_ asking on Stack Overflow but it breaks exactly where I expect it to do so (second line of the main) so I'm not able to enter into further detail. I'm not asking anyone to run the code for me, only for an idea or an input to confirm or invalid my assumption

Comment: The function passed to `mclRunMain` must have a specific signature: `int functionName(int, const char **)`. If done right, you won't need a cast in `mclRunMain` call; and conversely, if the call doesn't compile without a cast, you are holding it wrong.